# Passing an array of object to useState throws this error Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name})

Tags: reactjs, use-state, react-context

I am learning React Context API. I created a context named CartDataContext. In the provider when I use useState and pass an array of objects like [{id:1, name:"Item One"}] throws this error -> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Following is the CartContext.js Code

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useMemo } from 'react';

export const CartDataContext = createContext();

export const CartDataProvider = props => {

    const [cart, setCart] = useState([{id:1, name:"Item One"}]);

    return(
        <div>
            <CartDataContext.Provider value={[cart, setCart]}>
                { props.children }
            </CartDataContext.Provider>
        </div>
        
    )
}
```

In App.js This is how I am wrapping the Components within the context

```
<CartDataProvider>
    <Route path="/test" component={TestComponent} />
</CartDataProvider>
```

This is the TestComponent.js file code

```
    import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Button, Container } from 'reactstrap';
import { CartDataProvider } from '../contexts/CartContext';


const TestComponent = () => {

    const [cart, setCart] = useContext(CartDataProvider);
    const handleClick = () => {
        const item = {id: '3', name: "item 2"};

        setCart( prevCart => [...prevCart, item]); 
    }

    return (
        <div className="my-4">
            <Container>
                <h4>Test Component</h4>
                <p>Cart Context Value: {cart}</p>
                <Button onClick={handleClick}>Update Cart Context</Button>
            </Container>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default TestComponent;
```

Here is the screenshot of the error https://snipboard.io/t0VhZI.jpg

Please help me

Comment: You render an object... as the error says, show us the consumer....

Answer (score 1):

That because your `{cart}` is an `array` of object. So instead of render it like that, you need to enclosed them in some sort of `.map` or something: -

```
<div className="my-4">
  <Container>
    <h4>Test Component</h4>
    {cart.map(c => <p key={c.id}>Cart Context Value: {c.name}</p>)}
    <Button onClick={handleClick}>Update Cart Context</Button>
  </Container>        
</div>
```

here [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-o292nw?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FTestComponent.js) for reference